# Comparing performance of formatting a String a building with StringBuilder

Tags: java, performance, scala, string-formatting, jmh

I'm pretty new to jmh-microbenchmarking therefore this benchmark may have quite a lot of mistakes. I have some performance issue with writing logs in a pretty hot piece of code. Here is what we currently use for log formatting (written in Scala, as that we use `akka`):

```
  //From trait akka.event.LoggingAdapter
  def format(t: String, arg: Any*): String = {
    val sb = new java.lang.StringBuilder(64)
    var p = 0
    var startIndex = 0
    while (p < arg.length) {
      val index = t.indexOf("{}", startIndex)
      if (index == -1) {
        sb.append(t.substring(startIndex, t.length))
          .append(" WARNING arguments left: ")
          .append(arg.length - p)
        p = arg.length
        startIndex = t.length
      } else {
        sb.append(t.substring(startIndex, index))
          .append(arg(p))
        startIndex = index + 2
        p += 1
      }
    }
    sb.append(t.substring(startIndex, t.length)).toString
  }
```

Now, I wrote the following benchmark to compare this method's performance with building a string with just a string builder. The complete benchmark (uses akka-actor):

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Warmup(iterations = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 5)
@Fork(3)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class MyBenchmark {

    private static class TestActor extends UntypedActor{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Object message) throws Throwable { }
    }

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class St {
        ActorSystem system;
        Seq<Object> s;
        public String templateWith3Args;
        private LoggingAdapter adapter;
        public String result;

        @Setup(Level.Iteration)
        public void prepare(){
            system = ActorSystem.apply("test");
            s = scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(Arrays.<Object>asList("argument1", "argument2", "argument3").iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
            templateWith3Args = "{} some text {} another text {} someAnotherText";
            adapter = Logging.getLogger(system, system.actorOf(Props.create(TestActor.class)));
        }

        @TearDown(Level.Iteration)
        public void tearDown(){
            system.terminate();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.INLINE)
    public void akkaFormat(St st) {
        st.result = st.adapter.format(st.templateWith3Args, st.s);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.INLINE)
    public void simpleFormat(St st) {
        st.result = (new StringBuilder("argument1"))
                .append(" some text ")
                .append("argument2")
                .append(" another text ")
                .append("argument3")
                .append(" someAnotherText")
                .toString();
    }
}
```

The result of the benchmark was

```
Warmup Iteration = 7
Iteration = 7
Fork = 4

Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt    Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.akkaFormat    avgt   21  203.115 ± 9.637  ns/op
MyBenchmark.simpleFormat  avgt   21   36.081 ± 3.480  ns/op
```

So, the akka's version (according to this benchmark) is about 7 times slower.

I just would like to learn if it's actually slower or it's some benchmark-writing issues I missed. I don't think akka's heavy threading issues make this performance impact since I wrap all intialization within `@Setup`/`@Teardown` methods.

I added `@ComplierControl(CompilerControl.Mode.INLINE)` to reduce the impact of `akka`'s method calling.

Comment: Did you try use scalaMeter? JVM needs time to warm up.

Comment: @PavelOliynyk Not I didn't. Sure it does, I set warmup iteration to 7. Didn't mention it in the post.

Comment: @PavelOliynyk Added benchmark parameters.

Comment: Well. just try use what is there: https://scalameter.github.io/ Hope this would help.

Comment: @PavelOliynyk I will. But may I ask you do you have any idea about such difference in performance?

Comment: I would suspect akka provide some guaranties and doing some other work etc. Which is expected.

Comment: Also could be related to the fact that akka possibly use immutable types? Not sure but very likely.

Comment: If you want a definitive answer, then provide MCVE that others can run, and also *do profile* both tests to figure out where the hotspot are, what are the GC behaviors for both, etc

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev thank you for your advice. I tried it but it didn't really helpful. GC-activity in both becnhmarks I watched was 0.1% (jvisualvm shows so). What did you mean "where the hotspot are". Can't you expand it a bit?

Comment: JMH has embedded profilers (perfasm, stack) that can show where the hotspots in both tests are. Figuring this out is the important step in verifying/explaining the benchmark results.

Comment: Also, MCVE means "Complete" "Verifiable". For complex code with external dependencies, it means, in most cases, the project with everything set up.

Comment: But, you can already spot the trouble in the benchmark code: 1) akka's code reads arguments from the fields (that's what good benchmark is supposed to do), while stringBuilder has all embedded literals!; 2) storing the result in the field is not enough to avoid dead-code elimination; 3) INLINE hints are useless on @Benchmark methods here. The benchmark is one huge benchmark smell :) I had blindly rewritten it to (haven't compiled, haven't run, but this should be better): https://gist.github.com/shipilev/e9afaaf8b7b19e26064c01c631154925

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev Very interesting. About your comments. 1) Have no idea about why reading from fields is a good practice? I noticed you replaced it with return statement. What prevents it from dead-code elimination in that case?  2) Why? I thought if we store it in **a public** field compiler cannot optimize it away since it can be read from outside.

Comment: @St.Antario: Have you read the JMH Samples? They answer your questions in some detail. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/